# php natsort() not working as supposed to

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, natsort

I have a folder with 500+ jpgs named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ... 205.jpg etc. I need to output links to them in a table sorted by number.

After I `natsort()` an array of filenames and `print_r` it right away it outpust correctly, but when I try to loop through it and output in an html table it goes `1.jpg    10.jpg  100.jpg 101.jpg 102.jpg 104.jpg 105.jpg 106.jpg 107.jpg 108.jpg` etc.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$dir = 'files/'; // folder with 500+ images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ... 505.jpg etc.
$files = scandir($dir);

natsort($files);
print_r($files); // here outputs correctly: 'Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 1.jpg [106] => 2.jpg [213] => 3.jpg [324] => 4.jpg [432] => 5.jpg [543] => 6.jpg [652] => 7.jpg [699] => 8.jpg...'

$cols = 10;

echo "<table>";
$k = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
 if (($files[$i] != ".") && ($files[$i] != "..")) {
  if ($k % $cols == 0) {
   echo "<tr>";
  }
  echo "<td width='70px' align='center'>";
  $path = $dir . $files[$i];
  echo "<a href='$path'>";
  echo "$files[$i]";
  echo "</a>";
  echo "</td>";
  if ((($k + 1) % $cols == 0) || (($i + 1) == count($files))) {
   echo "</tr>";
  }

  $k++;
 }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you'll notice from your `print_r` of the result of the `natsort`, the keys have just been reordered, not renumbered, in the `$files` array. So when you loop on `$files[$i]` you get the same ordering as you started with. So you have two alternatives: use a `foreach` or use `array_values` to renumber the keys. Here's a small demo:

```
$files = array("12.png", "10.png", "2.png", "1.png");
print_r($files);
natsort($files);
print_r($files);  
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    echo $files[$i] . "\n";
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file . "\n";
}
$files = array_values($files);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    echo $files[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12.png
    [1] => 10.png
    [2] => 2.png
    [3] => 1.png
)

Array
(
    [3] => 1.png
    [2] => 2.png
    [1] => 10.png
    [0] => 12.png
)

12.png
10.png
2.png
1.png

1.png
2.png
10.png
12.png

1.png
2.png
10.png
12.png
```

Comment: I spent hours trying to a find a solution for this. php.net makes no mention of using array_values. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cymro no worries - I'm glad this helped you out.

Comment: Still, when the official php site never bothers to mention it, and it's a vital piece of information, it's kind of annoying. Once again, thanks for the insight you provided.